# Play framework 2.x generics

Tags: playframework, template-engine

I have below class hierarhy:

```
public class AbstractModel {
```

and class that inherit from above class:

```
public class Model1 extends AbstractModel {
```

and

```
public class Model2 extends AbstractModel {
```

Now I would like to transfer util.List one of above class implementations to play framework template engine(from Controller) but I don't wnat to know which class is exactly in List. Something like that:

```
public static Result reloadTableData() {
    List<Model1> models = new ArrayList<Model1>();
    return ok(myTemplate.render(models));
}
```

and myTemplate should look something like that:

```
@(users: List[AbstractModel])
```

this construction will return error and I dont know how to write a correct syntax.

Also in myTemplate I would like to distinguish those types (Model1 and Model2)
Also I dont know how this syntax should look like:(

Is anyone had this kind of problem? Each advice will be pleased.

Comment: type mismatch; found : java.util.List[models.AbstractModel] required: java.util.List[models.User]

Comment: when I remove all calls from template I've got:
error: incompatible types: List<User> cannot be converted to List<AbstractModel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `java.util.List<T>` is not covariant like Scala's `List[T]`. This means that even though `Model1` extends `AbstractModel`, a `List<Model1>` is not a `List<AbstractModel>`.  Therefore, you cannot pass a `List<Model1>` to `render`, when it expects `List<AbstractModel>`.

The only way I know to work around this is kind of ugly. Java arrays are covariant, so you can convert the `List` to an `Array` instead, and it will work.

```
public static Result reloadTableData() {
    List<Model1> models = new ArrayList<Model1>();
    Model1[] arr = models.toArray(new Model1[models.size()]);
    return ok(myTemplate.render(models));
}
```

Example view:

```
@(models: Array[AbstractModel])

@for(model <- models) {
    @if(model.isInstanceOf[Model1]) {
        I'm an instance of Model1
    }
    @if(model.isInstanceOf[Model2]) {
        I'm an instance of Model2
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work error says:
incompatible types: List<Model1> cannot be converted to List<AbstractModel>
when I replace List to Table error stays the same but it call problems with Model1[] table

Comment: In my opinion in template i should put something simmilar to <? extends AbstractModel> but I dont know how to do this :)

Comment: The example I provided compiles for me using play-java. I don't think Play templates support Java generics like you want. Using play-scala this could work, but I don't see a way using Java other than converting to an array.